# add a listener to Cordova events in a Backbone view and not to all document

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, backbone.js

I'd like to add a listener, for `Cordova` events, in a specific view of `Backbone`, so at this moment I did this using `document`:

```
var View = Utils.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
      document.addEventListener( "online", function(  ) { // cordova event
                alert("connected");
        // ....
        }, false);
  }

});
```

but every time I change view and go back to this `view` a new event listener is appended and so the document has many listeners, but I need only one.
So how can I add a event listener for once to that view and avoid creating new ones every time I go to this view?

Thanks

Comment: If the `online` event is view specific (i.e. if the view is not visible you do not want to listen for the `online` event). You could over-ride the view `remove` method and remove the event listener each time you close the view out.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved a similar issue in the past by doing the following:

- Add the listener on load of the application instead of when the view loads
- Have the listener call a function that checks for specific variable set to true or false
- When the specific view is initialized, set the variable to true
- When the specific view is replaced, or when any other view is initialized, set the variable to false

The function the listener calls will look something like this:

```
function onlineEventCallback () {
    if(app.checkOnline) {
        alert('connected');
    }
}
```

This will allow for the listener to only be set once, AND make sure that it only returns anything if the specific view is currently initialized.